# Are covering families of localizations stable under pushouts?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ct.category-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

For a commutative ring $A$, we call a finite family of localizations $A \to A_{S_i}$ (where $S_i$ are some subsets of $A$) a **covering** if the canonical morphism $A \to \prod A_{S_i}$ is an effective monomorphism. That is, this arrow is an equalizer to two arrows $\prod\limits_{i} A_{S_i} \rightrightarrows \prod\limits_{i, j} A_{S_i \cup S_j}$ (the usual condition from the definition of a sheaf).

> Is it correct that the coverings are stable under pushouts? That is, is it true that for a homomorphism $f \colon A \to B$ the induced family of localizations $B \to B_{f(S_i)}$ will be a covering?

If so, where can I read the proof?

Comment: Some comments on terminology: by definition, a map $A \to B$ in a category $\mathscr C$ is an *effective monomorphism* (not epimorphism) if $A \to B \rightrightarrows B \amalg_A B$ is an equaliser diagram. The pushout in commutative rings is the tensor product, but it is not clear to me that the natural map $(\prod_i A_{S_i}) \otimes_A (\prod_j A_{S_j}) \to \prod_{i,j} A_{S_i S_j}$ is always injective (this fails for general modules). So I think the name 'effective monomorphism' is not entirely the right one here.

Comment: Likewise, it is not clear that either variant coincides with the geometric condition that $\coprod_i \operatorname{Spec} A_{S_i} \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is an effective epimorphism. But all three coincide when the index set is finite, and in this case the condition is stable under base change (for instance since they are then pro-étale covers, so in particular fpqc covers, hence *universal* effective epimorphisms).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Of course, "effective monomorphism", thank you. I was just switching between algebra and geometry and accidentally made a typo.

Comment: In my condition, the index set is finite. Thank you very much for your comments!